# SOLID principles, and hard code configuration inside a class

Tags: solid-principles, magic-numbers

I have noticed in a lot of code lately that people put hard coded configuration (like port numbers, etc.) values deep inside of classes/methods, making it difficult to find, and also not configurable.

Is this a violation of the SOLID principles?  If not, is there another "principle" that I can cite to my team members about why it's not a good idea?  I don't want to just say "it's bad because I don't like it" but I am having trouble thinking of a good argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good argument against hardcoding a TCP port number in a class would be 'Context independence' violation. From [GOOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627), with my emphasis:

> Context Independence
>
> ... the
>   "context independence" rule helps us decide whether an object hides
>   too much or **hides the wrong information**. A system is easier to change
>   if its objects are context-independent; that is, if each object has no
>   built-in knowledge about the **system in which it executes**. This allows
>   us to take units of behavior (objects) and apply them in new
>   situations. To be context-independent, whatever an object needs to
>   know about the larger environment it’s running in **must be passed in**.

In this specific case of [Context Independence](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ContextIndependence) I would call it 'Environment Independence'. In other words a class with hardcoded port number has inappropriate dependency on a runtime OS environment, essentially stating '*I know that port 7778 will always be available*' which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The SOLID principles cover class design.

I suspect the idea that you should store configuration in configuration files isn't normally regarded as controversial enough to warrant inventing a special principle to persuade people! :)

Most people just figure it out from experience, the first time they try get the software running anywhere other than their own development workstation.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly SOLID, another principle of OOD is the The [Common Closure Principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommonClosurePrinciple), which states that classes that change together are packaged together.  While not exactly a class, you could stretch this idea to configuration information.  Since e.g. port numbers change based on different criteria than the surrounding code, it seems to violates this.

Answer (score 0):

The Single Responsibility Principle (the S in SOLID) states that a class should only have one reason to change. [This article](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) gives an example of a Modem interface, and discusses how the details of how to connect and hang up are a separate responsibility from the communication of data, and will probably change for different reasons. You could use this to make a similar case for why port numbers are an extra "reason for change", separate from the class's main responsibility.